# Java Spring добавление временной строки в бд

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate

Существует ли в Spring Аннотация, которая позволяет при занесении строки в таблицу удалить её через время? например, сутки. И если таковой нет, то как лучше действовать?

Comment: Такого нет. А что именно вы хотите реализовать?

Comment: Аннотации нет. Действовать лучше сохраняя текущую временную метку при занесении строки в таблицу, а после выбирать только те строки, у которых метка не старше суток.

Answer (score 0):

У спринга такого функционала нет

Я бы сделал новую таблицу в БД, где будет храниться условно 3 поля:

```
имя_таблицы; 
id_записи_которую_надо_удалить; 
дата_и_время_когда_нужно_удалить;
```

Далее я бы написал job с аннотацией @Scheduling (если у вас версия спринг-бута 2+, то необходимо еще будет навесить @EnableScheduling) и по ночам бы гонял этот джоб выбирая все записи которые необходимо удалять и делал бы соответствующую логику